# Streatch <table> to fill height of <td> in which it is contained

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an arbitrary number of tables whose heights I do not know in advance.

An outer table, and several inner tables contained like so within the outer table
`<tr><td><table></table></td></tr>`

The problem is that if one of the tables is larger than the others the remaining tables will not stretch to fill any gap above and below created by the larger table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  th,
  td {
    width: 14ch;
    height: 1ch;
  }
</style>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Wont Stretch</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="outer">
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 1ch"></th>
      <th style="width: 14ch">1</th>
      <th style="width: 1ch"></th>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 1ch">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>T1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>T1</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table id="col1">
            <tr>
              <td>test2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test2</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 1ch">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>T3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>T3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

I have tried `rowspan` and `table-layout: fixed`, both of which did nothing, but the only solution that came close was setting the height ahead of time which I cannot do as I don't know in advance what the largest table will be. Even then there was a gap I could not fill, it was merely close enough for nukes and hand grenades.

Comment: Why do you need the surrounding table? Also, how many rows/columns can we expect (on the inner and outer table)? Maybe we're dealing with a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) here.

Comment: My data comes grouped in columns. Each column represents a physical object that has sub divisions (rows) that are also subdivided by rows.

I'm trying to work around this by having an outer table that has the column numbers and two columns on the edge for labeling the parent rows.

Say in the above T1 is A and B. Test2 can be broken up into either 1,2, or 4 subdivisions each typically.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want to use nested tables? If I understand the question correctly you can achieve this by using 1 table and for example rowspan/colspan.

```css
table, th, td {
    border:1px solid black ;
    border-collapse: collapse ;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  th, td {
    width: 14ch ;
    height: 1ch ;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Rowspan 1 left</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Rowspan  1 right</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Rowspan 2 left</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Rowspan 2 right</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: The problem is this presumes that the middle sections are all 4 rows. 

The tables within tables are going to be id'd and have different numbers of rows some will have 4, some 2, some 8. It will be possible that at some point in the future they may have multiples of 3. I cannot know in advance how many rows there will be or the divisions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in an answer that the better solution is to use *rowspan* and *colspan*. But if you have to use the nested tables, one of the solution is to write class names to the tables and in CSS, make their height 100%.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

th,
td {
  width: 14ch;
  height: 1ch;
}

.table-left {
  height: 100%;
}

.table-center {
  height: 100%;
}

.table-right {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="outer">
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 1ch"></th>
    <th style="width: 14ch">1</th>
    <th style="width: 1ch"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 1ch">
      <table class="table-left">
        <tr>
          <td>T1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>T2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table id="col1" class="table-center">
        <tr>
          <td>test2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 1ch">
      <table class="table-right">
        <tr>
          <td>T3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            T4<br> break
            <br> break
            <br> break
            <br> break
            <br> break
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: when I run your code snippet it doesn't fix the problem. T1 doesn't stretch to fill its column.

Comment: I have renamed the left and right table's cells. Do you want entire left table is stretch to fit the height if height of the right table is increased? Or you want if height of T1 is increased then height of T3 should adopt T1's height similarly T2 and T4 should behave? I apologize if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: T1 and T2 should be 50% each of the first column

Comment: That's how it's behaving, if you run the snippet. :(

Comment: hmm for me it only shows t1 lining up with 1 of the test 2 rows.

I'm trying to get it to look like Nadine's, but without making it one table